# Are "Always On Failover Cluster Instances" and "SQL Server Failover Clustering" the same thing?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, hadr

I'm reading documentations of SQL Server. On this page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/windows-server-failover-clustering-wsfc-with-sql-server, it says:

> Both Always On Availability Groups and Always On Failover Cluster
> Instances use WSFC as a platform technology, registering components as
> WSFC cluster resources.

I'm a little bit confused. In previous version of SQL Server (like SQL Server 2008) there is a technology called *SQL Server Failover Clustering*, is it the same thing as *Always On Failover Cluster Instances*? Hope someone can clarify on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is the same thing. See section 3 which explains this term.

First lets get few terms straight.

1. **[Windows Server Failover Clustering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/windows-server-failover-clustering-wsfc-with-sql-server)**

> A Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) cluster is a group of
>   independent servers that work together to increase the availability of
>   applications and services. SQL Server 2016 takes advantage of WSFC
>   services and capabilities to support Always On availability groups and
>   SQL Server Failover Cluster Instances.

2. **[Always On Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server)**

> The Always On availability groups feature is a high-availability and
>   disaster-recovery solution that provides an enterprise-level
>   alternative to database mirroring. Introduced in SQL Server 2012,
>   Always On availability groups maximizes the availability of a set of
>   user databases for an enterprise. An availability group supports a
>   failover environment for a discrete set of user databases, known as
>   availability databases, that fail over together. An availability group
>   supports a set of read-write primary databases and one to eight sets
>   of corresponding secondary databases. Optionally, secondary databases
>   can be made available for read-only access and/or some backup
>   operations. An availability group fails over at the level of an
>   availability replica.
>
> Failovers are not caused by database issues such as a database
>   becoming suspect due to a loss of a data file, deletion of a database,
>   or corruption of a transaction log.

3. **[Always On Failover Cluster Instances (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server)**

> As part of the SQL Server Always On offering, Always On Failover
>   Cluster Instances leverages Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC)
>   functionality to provide local high availability through redundancy at
>   the server-instance level—a failover cluster instance (FCI). An FCI is
>   a single instance of SQL Server that is installed across Windows
>   Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) nodes and, possibly, across multiple
>   subnets. On the network, an FCI appears to be an instance of SQL
>   Server running on a single computer, but the FCI provides failover
>   from one WSFC node to another if the current node becomes unavailable.

Item number 2 and 3 can be combined and item 1 is a prerequisite for implementing any combination. 2 alone, 3 alone, 2 and 3 together.

When you combine 2 and 3 you get:  **[Failover Clustering and Always On Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-clustering-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server)**

> You can set up a second layer of failover at the server-instance level
>   by implementing SQL Server failover clustering together with the WSFC
>   cluster. An availability replica can be hosted by either a standalone
>   instance of SQL Server or an FCI instance. Only one FCI partner can
>   host a replica for a given availability group. When an availability
>   replica is running on an FCI, the possible owners list for the
>   availability group will contain only the active FCI node. + Always On
>   availability groups does not depend on any form of shared storage.
>   However, if you use a SQL Server failover cluster instance (FCI) to
>   host one or more availability replicas, each of those FCIs will
>   require shared storage as per standard SQL Server failover cluster
>   instance installation.

I would highly recommend reading [this FAQ](http://sqlha.com/2012/04/13/allans-alwayson-availability-groups-faq/) by SQLHA (Allan Hirt) which clarifies many basic questions when you combine these 3 items.

Comment: thanks for sharing.